# AMD control center doesn't save preferences

Tags: catalyst

Everytime when I edit the monitor preferences in AMD to multi-monitor or to a multidesktop, when I press save or apply the program just closes with no errors and the preferences hasn't been saved. If I try to do it via the Displays app that is built-in in ubuntu 11.10 I get the following error:

> **The selected configuration for displays could not be applied**
>   required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(2560, 1024), minimum=(320, 200), maximum=(1280, 1280)

I don't know if it helps but my graphics card is a ATI Radeon HD 4800 and my monitors are both 1280x1024. I'm running the proprietary driver without post-release updates because I always get an error trying to install that one.

Comment: Alright this is embaressing, I have been troubled by this for a while and then right after I post the question I found the answer. The solution was to start AMD up via the terminal with "gksudo amdcccl and then apparently it was able to save the settings. I logged out and in and went into the displays app and turned off the mirrored option and it works now.

Comment: Glad you found the answer! You should be able to post it as an answer below. Other people might have the same problem, and they'll be more likely to see it there than in a comment. Also, you'll be able to "accept" your answer after a couple days.

Comment: actually there should be two launchers for the amd catalyst control center a normal one and one that says '(Administrative)' at the end use this launcher and all is good

Answer (score 1):

Under 'Preferences' in your system menu, you should find two versions of the AMD Catalyst Control Center.  One of which should open with superuser privileges.

Alternatively, you can try running `gksudo amdcccl` if you are unable to find such a menu entry.

If you run into serious problems and wish to start again, or you simply would like to reset all of your configuration regarding X Server and your graphics card, try running `sudo aticonfig --initial` or `sudo aticonfig --initial=dual-head`.  Only use the latter if you have multiple graphics cards.

Remember that most changes made through AMD Catalyst Control Center will require restarting X Server, which can be done by logging out and logging back into the system or rebooting entirely.